# Why the laravel make:controller command gives Too many arguments, expected arguments "name"

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-9

I want to create a controller with a model. I used artisan.

`php artisan make:controller –-model=RequestLog --resource ReqLogController`

But the result was,
`Too many arguments to "make:controller" command, expected arguments "name".`

I read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers) but didn't find a solution.

And I tried `php artisan help make:controller`, and the result was,

```
Description:
  Create a new controller class

Usage:
  make:controller [options] [--] <name>

Arguments:
  name                   The name of the class

Options:
      --api              Exclude the create and edit methods from the controller     
      --type=TYPE        Manually specify the controller stub file to use
      --force            Create the class even if the controller already exists      
  -i, --invokable        Generate a single method, invokable controller class
  -m, --model[=MODEL]    Generate a resource controller for the given model
  -p, --parent[=PARENT]  Generate a nested resource controller class
  -r, --resource         Generate a resource controller class
  -R, --requests         Generate FormRequest classes for store and update
      --test             Generate an accompanying PHPUnit test for the Controller    
      --pest             Generate an accompanying Pest test for the Controller       
  -h, --help             Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet            Do not output any message
  -V, --version          Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi   Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction   Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]        The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose   Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

In my knowledge, the command that I used was correct according to the help.

Comment: either the first or second dash in ```--model``` is not a dash but rather a special character, try typing it again

Comment: The name comes first, php artisan make:controller ReqLogController –-model=RequestLog --resource

Comment: @Mehrwarz The "usage" part mentions it last thogh

Comment: I think it is a typing mistake  in documentation or it has come from earlier versions. have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#specifying-the-resource-model

Comment: Not a typo, everything is fine with the documentation. As AliRahimi mentioned (and as you can see with the code OP posted), one of the dashes is not correct

Comment: @AliRahimi It worked. I just copy and paste the command, I think that’s why it happened. Thank you.